# In Vanilla JS - Change a variable once a user finishes typing

Tags: javascript, html

Without using jQuery - I am trying to simply change a var based on a input's value - when the user finishes typing then update the div value.  Is there a way to do it without writing a function to fire onchange?  Something like if a change happen change var.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="12" id="inNum" />
</div>
<div id="rooms"></div>

var disNum = document.getElementById('inNum').onchange;
document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML  = disNum.value;
```

Comment: Could you link to a js fiddle?

Comment: _"do it without writing a function to fire onchange? Something like if a change happen change var."_ So you want to have it change without using onchange??

Comment: @GSaunders Why not make your own? Copy + paste 6 lines of code, not that tough.

Comment: "Is there a way to do it without using onchange?": no. "Is there a way to do it without jQuery": yes, use onchange.

Comment: @slebetman "Is there a way to do it without using onchange?": yes; use a setInterval loop.

Comment: Would you like the variable to constantly update (as the user is typing) or once they click outside the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to listen to one of `keypress`, `keydown` or `keyup`.

I tried listening to `onchange` but that would only fire when the input was blurred; maybe this is your current problem, or actually your desired behaviour. If this is your desired behaviour, just replace `.onkeyup` below with `.onchange`.

The only other way you could do this (that I can think of) is by using some `setInterval` loop, and re-checking the state in each iteration, but really, that would be a terrible idea.

[Here, I've made a JSFiddle to demonstrate my approach.](http://jsfiddle.net/ydsopc7p/)

```js
var disNum = document.getElementById('inNum');

disNum.onkeyup = function(){
  document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML = disNum.value;
};
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="12" id="inNum">
</div>
<div id="rooms"></div>
```

Comment: So only way to do this is to have a function that fires onkeyup?  There is no way to tie the two together so the value auto pulls/gets passed along to the div? Like:

`var disNum = document.getElementById('inNum').onkeyup;
document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML = disNum.value;`